# how to get color of embed in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a bot in discord
I want to send the bot some specific message according to the color of the previous embed

```
  if (message.channel.id == channelid):
  embeds = message.embeds
  for embed in embeds:
     if embed.color == 0x088AFB:
             await message.channel.trigger_typing()
             await message.channel.send("ub")
```

this is my code
when I run it the bot don't give any error too
but it also don't send the thing which I want it to

Answer (score 3):

embed.color is of type discord.Color instead of the hexadecimal one you're comparing it to. The way to compare them is by wrapping the hexadecimal code in a discord.Color class.

```
embed.color == discord.Color(0x088AFB)
```

If the embed color has it's hex code as `088AFB` this should return true.